# Where is syslog.conf file on ubuntu 10

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, syslog

i want to LOG my droppped packets in firewall.

The tutorial told me write some lines in /etc/syslog.conf

I have searched but could not foound anything named syslog.conf

There was the file called rsyslog.conf

Are both same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not the same program, but it is the same objective : log all the reporting problems.
By default, there is a /etc/rsyslog.d dir where you can put all your modifications. Ths syntax is not the same that syslog.conf.

Comment: Well... take a look at /etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf. The beginning of the file definitely uses the same syntax than the old syslogd :) so it is possible to use the old syntax, but also the more versatile one.

Answer (score 2):

Recent Ubuntu releases switched from the old *syslogd* to *rsyslog*, which is kind of backwards compatible with the old syslog daemon but with more features. So modifying the */etc/rsyslog.conf* MIGHT work.

What do you have in mind?

Comment: i want to log my iptable messages like this 
http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/force-iptables-to-log-messages-to-a-different-log-file.html

can i add those lines in rsyslog.conf file

Comment: Yes, you can. However, please be warned that this doesn't just put the iptables messages into that log file, the file will receive all log messages that posted for the "kern" target, which does include other things as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the old syntax, be careful of the flags that you 'll use on the executable.

check at the manual on -c flag.
You may have problems if you don't use it.